# how to expand network to another floor

Tags: networking, switch, local-area-network, wide-area-network

I have a small business on the ground floor of a commercial building. We are planning to rent the 4th floor in this building  too, so I need to extend our network to the 4th floor.

Presently, here on the ground floor, I have a UniFi Switch PRO 48 PoE (behind a UniFi Security Gateway).

Can I just buy another switch for the 4F office and bridge the switches with an SPF module?

https://store.ui.com/collections/operator-accessories/products/sfp-modules?variant=31221652109

Never done this before . . .  so not sure if there are other considerations I should be aware of, or any unknown unknowns.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I just buy another switch for the 4F office and bridge the switches with an SPF module?

Basically, yes. You can just connect two switches to form a larger network. Depending on the workloads you're serving, you need to consider the required link capacity - is the switch-to-switch interconnect fast enough for the expected (shared) load?

If you use fiber to connect the switches you'll need the corresponding SFP(+) modules - 1G or 10G depending on the required speed, and -SX/SR for multi-mode fiber or -LX/LR for single-mode fiber.

Depending on the distance, you could also use Cat. 5e twisted-pair cabling for the interconnect (1G only with those switches).